# Zabbix trigger if text string is not present in last value

Tags: zabbix

I have created a custom template with the following item :

```
eventlog[Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational,"\Sending data",,TaskScheduler,201,,skip]
```

Which gives out the following value :

The Task Scheduler has completed the task "Sending data", instance "{de22c11d-4a46-42a1-bf63-4ee91bd9c3gc}", action "C:\sending_data.exe" with the return code 0.

I'd like to create a trigger for when the string "with the return code 0" is not present in the latest value.

So far here is what I have for the trigger :

```
not(find(/windows_acd-groupe_active/eventlog[Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational,"\Sending data",,TaskScheduler,201,,skip],#1,,"\"with the return code 0.\""))
```